# Joomla like component architecture.. Starting from scratch

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, joomla

> Blockquote

Edited:

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/06/28/a-modular-approach-to-web-development/

The above approach is what I'm looking for. So are there php frameworks available which will allow me to create modular structure like above for my code ?

Edited:

> Blockquote

I would like to know which is the current best php framework which is 100% modular like joomla component architecture.

In joomla all you have to do is upload a set of files under the "components" directory and you can add "any" kind of complex functionality to joomla.

I want to develop php applications from scratch and I want all of my applications to have the **same ease of joomla's component architecture**. So Im currently looking for a php framework.

So which is the best way to go about if I want to do the above ?

Should I choose a php framework like codeignitor or zend etc ? but you see, even if is use them, Suppose if I have to create a new function I have to upload files to atleast 3 directories i.e controller, model and view. But you see in joomla all I have to do is upload all the files of course suitably structured into just a single directory called "components" and the rest is taken care of automatically

So what is the best way to go forward ?

Shanthi

Comment: The best way to go forward is to download Joomla and look at their sourcecode to learn how they did it.

Comment: That was my first thought. But I would like to strip down joomla completely and use only the essential parts. I like joomla's component structure very much and would like to give the users of MY product the same convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is a CMS system AFAIK so you cant really compare a PHP framework to it.

In terms of modularity Zend Framework has an excellent excellent, simple to implement module structure.

You sat that to add complex functionality to joomla you upload files in the correct structure and joomla does it for you, well as long as you create your module files in the right structure for ZF it will work too......

Comment: Martswite so to add new function when using zend framework we need to add files to Model, view and controller folders isnt it ? Or we need to just upload the files to some "plugins" directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is same as my question. but it was for 4 months ago.
I tried to find out how can i create such modular system. After some searching I understood that we should have a single directory like 'components' as you said, and put every data of modules in it. but how we should use them ?. Easy !. just create an handler (php file) that control your installation, uninstalling, positioning, settings. In fact i just solve 3 of them. positioning is so hard i think so, i never do it till now.

if you want an example of my explanation, just tell me to create it. I'll send it for you. :)

Comment: MahanGM, Is this available in a php framework now ? Or how did you do it ?

Comment: yeah. i don't know why the others think so hard !?. Modularity is so easy. If you think I'm talking out of (Programming Engineering Rules and Structures), It's right but I produced my own ways. I'm agree with PurplePilot. He told everything that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there is a difference as Joomla et al as CMS's and therefore come in at a higher level of functionality than a framework, but of course with less flexibility.

However you might want to explore Symfony 2 and Lithium (Cake 3?). Both are designed to only use PHP 5.3 and greater and both use the namespace functionality in PHP. I have done less with Lithium but certainly in Symfony 2 everything (well nearly everything is a plugin making the framework modular and much easier to manage.

However you will never be able to compare the two Framework/CMS in exactly the same way as they are both built and designed for different purposes and with varying constraints.

N.B. Neither Symfony 2 or Lithium are production ready at present. Symfony is aiming at March 2011, not clear on Lithium's 1 dot oh date

[edit]
A number of answers here plump for Zend. What needs to be clear is that there are two types of framework (yes ok lot's and lot's) but being simplistic there are Full Stack and Glue.

Glue frameworks like Zend tend to be free and easy allowing you to use some parts and not others as you wish. So although nominally MVC you can easily implement Zend with V and C but not use M. You can write all your database calls manually in the controller etc.

Full Stack such as Symfony mean you pretty well use all of whether you like it or not. On the data side you use and ORM, Doctrine or Propel and a large amount of the framework is controlled from configuration files in YAML/XML. In this respect Symfony is very like Ruby et al. Please note this is not a recommendation or criticism of either.

Joomla in my opinion is gluey (but not a framework) but hey why use something that is 90% built and then rewrite 75% of it? Oh yes because the customer asks and your boss is unaware of the problems, i remember now.

Comment: I think Zend Framework 2 will also be rolling out namespaces and such like... Not sure when a stable release will be coming though

Comment: Ok so if I code using simple PHP 5 and if I use namespaces can I achieve truly modular programming ? If so are there any examples/tutorials available ?

Comment: What I want can be found here http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/06/28/a-modular-approach-to-web-development/  It talks about MVC and then modular programming. I know almost all of the present php frameworks support MVC. So my question is can anyone let me know which among  the present frameworks like CI, zend, cakephp etc supports this kind of true modular programming out of the box so as to speak ?

Answer (score 0):

well i think you are comparing apples to exotic devil fruits or something.
you are adding modules to a cms and exepct the same from a famework. 
it doesnt work like this.
the mvc structure you are talking about (model - view - controller) makes a lot of sense and helps you to keep your code organised and to keep up good class coherency.
its a design pattern which has evolved to a de facto standard and has been adopted by almost every framework.

zend framework is probably the best way to go for you.
its layouting engine and stuff is not as fast as one could wish, but it features execellent modularity. you can even partly overload core classes to suit your needs in your "module".
only abstract classes dont work (how should they?), thats why they are almonst never used.

if you really really wanna go with a very flexible excellent system and performance is not the most important point for you, you should get going with magento, which takes the modularity and flexibility even to a higher level by adding an xml structure to zend framework that allows you to organice all your pages, manage your dependencies, rewrite your model componenents etc.

but be a aware that the more you want the more performance you will loose. my personal fav from the frameworks out there is codeigniter, but i designed my own for my needs...

Comment: Joe Hopfgartner, I too would really like to use codeigniter. for example say I start coding a complex ecommerce system using codeignitor and I use all the best coding practices. Down the line , Is it possible to add a new functionality say a wishlist, just buy uploading a few files under a single directory or create a module system where I upload a zip file containing the module and the program does the rest ? The idea is I will create the base ecommerce system and sell it. and 3rd party programmers should find it very easy to create modules for my product. Is it easy with codeignitor ?